# Check if session id is equal to a specific value

Tags: php, session

I have this code right here and it still proceeds to the next code line despite it I know returning false. Hope somebody can help me on this one.

I want to throw a user out if the user tries to go this specific php file without being logged in and if the user is not id 32 on session.

```
    if(!isset($_SESSION['username']) && $_SESSION['id'] != 32) { 
    session_destroy();
    echo "<script> alert('Access Denied \nThrowing you out...'); window.location='loginform.php'; </script>";
    }
```

I also echoed the session id using a different user and it echoes 45 so I don't know why it proceeds.

I echoed !isset($_SESSION['username']) and when logged in, it shows 1 so it's TRUE but shouldn't that be FALSE because session username is already set?

Comment: If userID is confirmed to be 45, then that second statement should return true. So that means that the first statement is NOT returning true. So that means $_Session['username'] is not null. You can check this by removing "!" in front of isset and running the line again

Answer (score 0):

Try Like this

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['username']) || $_SESSION['id'] != 32) 
{ 
  session_destroy();
  echo "<script> alert('Access Denied \nThrowing you out...'); 
  window.location='loginform.php'; </script>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can check id exist or not in session and also id is equal to 32 or not. Hope below code is works for you.

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['id']) && $_SESSION['id'] != 32) { 
   session_destroy();
   echo "<script> alert('Access Denied \nThrowing you out...');window.location='loginform.php'; </script>";
 }
```

Comment: sadly it didn't work aswell :( must be something inside the if statement.

Answer (score 0):

try this one please

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['username']) && $_SESSION['id'] != 32) { 
    session_destroy();

    echo "<script> alert('Access Denied \nThrowing you out...');
     header("location:loginform.php");
    exit();
}
```